# How to reference an adjacent cell in google sheets relative to the selected cell

Tags: google-sheets, documentation

I am trying to use the `=sum()` function in google sheets, and so far, that's all I have typed into the targeted cell. For example, I want D3 to be the sum of C2 and D2. I know how to type that. `=sum(C2,D2)`. But I want cells D3 thru D30 to have the same equation, relative to their adjacent cells. Something like this `=sum(cell to the left, cell above)`. Let me know if you need more elaboration, or if you have the answer, great!

Comment: Just drag down your formula. It will automatically adjust ranges.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

> **Paste** this formula in the first cell next to your numbers or take a look at the [**Example Sheet**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VVZClPPaP1g_3lwIt-6gMvM99xMEku1ZtOp1g8UbhNw/edit?usp=sharing)

```
=IF(C2="",,IF(ISNUMBER(D1),C2+D1,0))
```

[image]

### Explanation

- We check the above cell `ISNUMBER` if so we calculate `C2+D1` if not we put `0`
- `IF(C2="",,` to calculate onlt when the range `C2:C` is not Empty.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a single formula you can also try

```
=INDEX(IF(ISNUMBER(C2:C), SUMIF(ROW(C2:C),"<="&ROW(C2:C),C2:C),))
```

[image]